# XRM.SDK QueryExpression ConditionOperator.Like

Tags: xrm

How do I execute a query in the CRM (using QueryExpression from XRM.SDK) so that a values in one of the fields will have a certain length?
And what there are special characters for work with patterns that are used with the operator ConditionOperator.Like any '%'? I have not found any information on this subject.

Answer (score 0):

There is no similar to Length operator (in t-sql) in CRM queries.
If you want to use Like operator you should use patterns with '%' symbol in the same way as you build queries in t-sql.

Comment: Can I use '_', [] and [^] too?

Comment: In what cases do you want to use mentioned strings?